# Is there any way in an ASP.NET MVC app to determine which timeout setting caused execution of a report to fail?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I have a long running report in my app which causes the request to time out, and I want to increase the time limit but I'm not sure where that limit is. I tried setting the command timeout for my `DataContext` to 99999 seconds but even before that time was up it timed out anyway. I see an `executionTimeout="120"` set in the web.config but that can't be it because it ran for more than two minutes; I think this setting is ignored in debug mode. There's also this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/User/" timeout="720" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
```

But that's only for logging in, right? So how can I tell what timeout setting I need to adjust in order to prevent my report from timing out?

Comment: This setting has nothing to do with reports. It's about forms authentication. You didn't even explain what report engine you use, what errors you got

Comment: What report engine? It's Microsoft's RDLC engine, or something like that - I'm not entirely sure how that all works. The error I'm getting is a generic browser error: Can’t reach this page. It took too long to connect to this website. Error Code: INET_E_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Comment: Eventually it will be impractical to have the request sit and wait for a response. Best to invest now in a queuing and status check mechanism so that you can decouple the http request from the report runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Can you capture the exception in your global.asax and check the stacktrace. This would help you to find the location from where exception is thrown.

Comment: I don't think it was an exception; it was just a timeout when running the report. By the way, I think this answer would be more appropriately written as a comment, just for reference for next time. Thanks! :)